# Add Group in SignalR on MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr-hub

How to Add SignalR in mvc i have Already Added in View

```
 <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js")'></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    $("#btnPopUpLogin").hide();
    var MyHub = $.connection.foxHub;
    var BlogId = '@ViewBag.BlogId';
    //-------------- Load Messages
    LoadClientMessage(MyHub);
    //----------------- Start Hub
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        LoadEvents(MyHub, BlogId);
    });

});
function LoadClientMessage(myHub) {
    myHub.client.getMessages = function (userName, message) {
        $("#Message").val("");
        $("#commentList tbody").prepend('<tr><td>' + userName + '</td><td>' + message + '</td></tr>');

    }
}
function LoadEvents(myHub, blogId) {
    myHub.server.connect(blogId);
    $("#btnComment").click(function () {
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <text>
        var Message = $("#Message").val();
        myHub.server.sendMessage('@WebSecurity.CurrentUserId', '@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName', blogId, Message);
        </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
        $("#btnPopUpLogin").fadeIn(100);
        </text>
        }
    });

}


</script>
```

and Add One View Table for view as id "commentList". but i also added Hub class to my model.. but it is not working.. my back end code is correctly working.. what i have to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

add this...